# Why is $ \overline{e^z} = e^\overline{z} $?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

How can you conjugate an entire function? $ \overline{exp(z)} $ I need an equivalent.

I thought this is only possible with complex numbers.

What is the proof for $ \overline{e^z} = e^\overline{z} $ ?
(Please don't involve a power series here.)

Comment: What's your definition of $e^z$? It should follow smoothly from it.

Comment: You can take complex conjugate of non-complex numbers but since they have imaginary component 0 this is the identity

Comment: You are saying this is only possible with complex numbers, but if $z\in\mathbb{R}, \overline{z}=z$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\overline{e^z}=\overline{e^xe^{iy}}=e^x(\overline{\cos y+i\sin y})=e^x(\cos y-i\sin y)=e^x(\cos(-y)+i\sin(-y))=e^{x-iy}=e^{\overline{z}}$$

Answer (score 5):

Using another definition.
$$
e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\;z^k
\\
\overline{e^z} = \overline{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\;z^k}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \overline{\;\frac{1}{k!}\;}\;\overline{z^k}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\;{\overline{z}\;}^k
= e^{\overline{z}}
$$

Comment: $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \overline{\;\frac{1}{k!}\;}\;\overline{z^k}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\;{\overline{z}\;}^k $$

Why?

Comment: $(1/k!)$ is real; conjugate is multiplicative: $\overline{ab} = \overline{a}\;\overline{b}$; and induction.

Comment: We don't use induction on infinity, right?

Comment: Using $\overline{ab} = \overline{a}\;\overline{b}$, we prove $\overline{z^k} = \overline{z}^k$ for $k \in \mathbb N$ by induction on $k$.  I do not know what you mean by "induction on infinity".

Answer (score 2):

But really, if $f$ is nice (analytic) and $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $z\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(\bar z) = \overline{f(z)}$.

Comment: To be proved using my proof.  Or, how about proving it with the Cauchy-Riemann equations?  (How to use $f(x)$ real?)

Comment: @GEdgar: Your proof would work just fine since the coefficients in the Taylor series (at real pts) turn out to be real. Or you can say $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(\bar z)}$ are two analytic functions coinciding on the real line so they coincide (related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle). Of course your proof just explains everything.

Comment: @GEdgar: Seems like the question on how to prove it with Cauchy-Riemann is quite interesting.