# Does $\overline {\lim\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac {z^n}{n!}}=\lim\overline {\sum _{n=0}^{k}\frac{z^n}{n!}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

A book I'm reading claims that  $\overline{Exp(z)}= Exp(\overline z)$ where the exponetial function is defined as $\sum_ {n=0 }^{\infty } \frac{z^n } {n! } $

Verifying this would mean verifying that  $\overline {\lim_ {k \to \infty }  \sum_{n=0 } ^{k }  \frac {z^n } {n! }  }= \lim _ {k \to \infty }\overline {\sum _{n=0 } ^{k }\frac {z^n } {n! }  }  $, but I don't know about any rules for taking conjugation inside a limit. How is this motivated?

---

Note that I don't think this is a duplicate of [Why is $ \overline{e^z} = e^\overline{z} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109091/why-is-overlineez-e-overlinez)
since Gedgars answer does not motivate why this can be done.

Comment: Okey if ${z _n = a _n + b _n } $ is a complex sequence, then $\lim z _n = \lim a  _n + \lim b _n  $ and $\lim a  _n - \lim b _n =\lim a  _n + \lim -b _n  $?

Answer (score 5):

Complex conjugation is continuous.

To prove this, first prove
$$
\overline{z-w} = \overline{z} - \overline{w}
$$
then use it to show
$$
\bigl|\overline{z}-\overline{w}\bigr| = \bigl|z-w\bigr|
$$
Finally, in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of "continuous", take $\varepsilon = \delta$.